# SQL where clause from concatenated string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a string which contains a comma delimited list of id's which I want to use in a where clause.

How can I achieve this? Essentially I have:

```
set @ids = '5,8,14,5324,'

SELECT * FROM theTable WHERE Id IN (@ids)
```

but @ids is a varchar and Id is an int.

Any ideas much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option instead of dynamic SQL would be to parse @ids into a #TempTable (one example of a parsing function is [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1665)) and then join against it.

```
select *
    from theTable t1
        inner join #TempTable t2
            on t1.Id = t2.Id
```

or you can bypass the #TempTable completely (the following code assumes the parsing function from the link above)

```
select *
    from theTable t1
        inner join dbo.fnParseStringTSQL(@ids, ',') t2
            on t1.Id = cast(t2.string as int)
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use dynamic SQL with your current approach. Ensure your `@ids` has the trailing comma trimmed.

```
DECLARE @DynSQL NVARCHAR(2000)

SELECT @DynSQL=  'SELECT * FROM theTable WHERE Id IN ('  + @ids + ')'

EXEC  sp_executesql @DynSQL
```

Remember that dynamic SQL runs in its own scope. The simple select will work fine.

Comment: @DynSQL must be ntext/nchar/nvarchar

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use a stored proc with a table variable as the input variable and then join to that table to get your results.